# Domino Program Issues

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct, switch-statement

I am trying to get this code done quickly for class as I have already been writing it for upwards of 10 hours and I just can't get it to work. Essentially what it is, is a domino program where you enter the first number of the domino, the second number, and then a flag (y will be standard- will have to switch to n when dice is removed). Currently I am receiving errors stating the following:
1. warning: format '%c' expects argument of type 'char *', but argument 2 has type 'void(*)   ()' 
2. error: called object 'print' is not a function
3. error: expected expression before 'Domino'

I have sat and researched this issue for hours online and I know I am missing something small. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated

```
 #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int getIndex();
void addDomino();
void removeDomino();
void print();
void quit();

typedef struct Domino{
int * i;
int * x;
int * y;
}Domino;

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    int NumDom, DomNum1, DomNum2, DomIndex, Index, input;
    char MainMenu;

//Startup
    printf("Enter the max number of dominos:");
    scanf("%d",&NumDom);
    void * add = malloc(size(Domino)*1);
    void * remove = malloc(offset(Domino)*1);
    void * print = malloc(sizeof(Domino)*10);
    //int domino[NumDom][3];
    //int dom[0][3] = {Index, DomNum1, DomNum2};

    //Main Menu
   // printf("Enter (p) to print (a) to add (r) to remove and (q) to quit\n");
    // printf(":");
    // scanf("%s",&MainMenu);

    printf("Enter (p) to print (a) to add (r) to remove and (q) to quit\n");
    scanf("%c%c%c%c \n", addDomino, removeDomino, print, quit);
    switch(input)
    {
    case 'a':
        addDomino();
        break;
    case 'r':
        removeDomino();
        break;
    case 'p':
        print();
        break;
    case 'q':
        quit();
        break;
    printf(":\n");
 }       
}
//Add
void addDomino(DomNum1, DomNum2)
{
    printf("Enter number 1\n");
    printf(":");
    scanf("%d", &DomNum1);
    printf("Enter number 2\n");
    printf(":");
    scanf("%d", &DomNum2);
}

    //Print
void printDomino(DomNum1, DomNum2)
{
    printf("Printing Dominos\n");
    printf("Domino # (%d,%d)\n",DomNum1,DomNum2);
}    
    //Remove
void removeDomino(DomIndex)
{
    printf("Enter the index:%d", DomIndex);
    scanf("%d", &DomIndex);
}

    //Quit
void quit()
{
    printf("All done\n");
}
```

**HERE IS THE ORIGINAL CODE THAT WORKS MINUS ALL MY FUNCTION ISSUES**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Domino{
    int * i;
    int * x;
    int * y;
}Domino;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    int NumDom, DomNum1, DomNum2, DomIndex, Index;
    char MainMenu;

//Startup
    printf("Enter the max number of dominos:");
    scanf("%d",&NumDom);

//int domino[NumDom][3];
//int dom[0][3] = {Index, DomNum1, DomNum2};

//Main Menu
printf("Enter (p) to print (a) to add (r) to remove and (q) to quit\n");
printf(":");
scanf("%s",&MainMenu);

//Add
printf("Enter number 1\n");
printf(":");
scanf("%d", &DomNum1);
printf("Enter number 2\n");
printf(":");
scanf("%d", &DomNum2);

//Print
printf("Printing Dominos\n");
printf("Domino # (%d,%d)\n", DomNum1, DomNum2);

//Remove
printf("Enter the index:5");
scanf("%d", &DomIndex);

//Quit
printf("All done\n");

}
```

Comment: You need a basic C book.

Comment: The definitions for your functions have parameters, but the declarations and calls don't. Should there be parameters? Should you be passing values for them? Edit: Also, your parameters don't appear to have datatypes: Should you have, for example, `removeDomino(int domIndex)`?

Comment: I strongly recommend you visit your prof or a TA to get some extra help getting basic syntax and programming concepts down. Start with a much smaller program than this, get that working, and then try this again.

Comment: I have tried asking my prof for help multiple times and he doesn't give any sort of useful advice. I've also tried some of my programming friends. I can handle the basic stuff but this advanced is way beyond me. And can't wait on this program :( it's due in 3 hours.

Answer (score 0):

As for the first issue - you're passing function pointer to scant function, I don't understand what you're trying to achieve. 
Just give it `input` variable and that's all.

Comment: Ultimately here are the parameters for what is supposed to be happening.
This assignment will be to add and remove dominos from an array of dominos. Your structure will be a domino. It will hold 3 fields (used, number1 and number2).
The used field will either hold Y or N. If used is a Y, then number1 and number 2 are the two numbers for the domino. Your main function will only allocate the array
of dominos and read the option for which action to take. Actions are print, add, remove and quit (exits the program).

Comment: The getIndex function will get the index to be removed.
The addDomino function will find a free spot, and then read in number1 and number2 for that domino. It will also set that domino as being used (used = ‘Y’).
The removeDomino function will remove the domino at the location index. This can be done by setting the used flag for that index to ’N’);
The print function will print out all the used dominos (used field = Y). 
My professor is super strict so I am trying to get this working perfectly but I was up super late working on this and feel like I am running around in circles

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you're telling `scanf` to scan for a character, but you're not giving it a character to put the value into. For example, this:

```
printf("Enter (p) to print (a) to add (r) to remove and (q) to quit\n");
scanf("%c%c%c%c \n", addDomino, removeDomino, print, quit);
```

Makes no sense. You're asking the user to pick a command but asking for 4 characters to be entered. You just need something like this:

```
char command;
printf("Enter (p) to print (a) to add (r) to remove and (q) to quit\n");
scanf("%c", &command);
```

You've also not typed the parameters to your functions. For example this:

```
void addDomino(DomNum1, DomNum2)
```

looks like it ought to be this:

```
void addDomino(int DomNum1, int DomNum2)
```

and at the top, where you had this:

```
void addDomino()
```

it should look like this:

```
void addDomino(int, int)
```

This will allow you to call `addDomino()` from inside `main()`.